# Styled-System Button Not Rendering Properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am trying to create a button component using Styled-System.  Everything was working fine not long ago, but now only part of the styles are rendering properly and I can't figure out why.

Here is my setup...

Here is the component file:

```
// Button.js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { color, space, fontSize, buttonStyle } from 'styled-system'

import { buttonDefaults, buttonSize } from '../styles/theme'

const Button = styled('button')(
  {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    display: 'inline-block',
    letterSpacing: '.5px',
    outline: 0,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
  },
  color,
  space,
  fontSize,
  buttonSize,
  buttonStyle
)

Button.defaultProps = {
  ...buttonDefaults,
}

export default Button
```

Here is the theme file:

```
import breakpoints from './themes/breakpoints'
import colors from './themes/colors'
import fontSizes from './themes/fontSizes'
import spacing from './themes/spacing'

import { buttonStyles as buttons, buttonSizes } from './themes/buttons'

const theme = {
  colors,
  spacing,
  fontSizes,
  breakpoints,
  buttons,
  buttonSizes,
}

export { buttonDefaults } from './themes/buttons'
export { buttonSize } from './themes/buttons'

export default theme
```

Here is the button theme file:

```
// buttons.js
import { variant } from 'styled-system'

export const buttonDefaults = {
  backgroundColor: `dark`,
  border: 'none',
  borderRadius: `2px`,
  color: `light`,
  fontSize: `body`,
  height: `36px`,
  lineHeight: `36px`,
  padding: `0 16px`,
  boxShadow: `box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
                          0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
                          0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`,
}

export const buttonStyles = {
  flat: {
    color: '#343434',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    transition: 'background-color .2s',
  },
  block: {
    display: 'block',
  },
}

export const buttonSize = variant({
  prop: 'size',
  key: 'buttonSizes',
})

export const buttonSizes = {
  small: {
    height: '32.4px',
    lineHeight: '32.4px',
    fontSize: '13px',
  },
  large: {
    height: '54px',
    lineHeight: '54px',
    fontSize: '15px',
    padding: '0 28px',
  },
}
```

The problem seems to be with the `buttonDefaults` object.  Some (but not all) of the items in that object are getting rendered -- namely:

- color
- background-color
- padding
- font-size

But these styles are not getting rendered:

- border
- height
- line-height
- box-shadow
- border-radius

And I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

P.S.  In case it makes a difference -- this is a Gatsby on codesandbox.  Here is the URL:  https://codesandbox.io/s/learningstyledsystemandrebass-8j6im?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The defaults won't work without making sure their respective setters are part of the initial `Button`'s setup.

For example, adding `borders` & the rest to Button fixes it:

```js
import { color, space, fontSize, buttonStyle, borders,  boxShadow} from 'styled-system'
const Button = styled('button')(
  {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    display: 'inline-block',
    letterSpacing: '.5px',
    outline: 0,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
  },
  color,
  space,
  borders, // Doubt the order matters, but they need to be here.
  boxShadow,
  fontSize,
  buttonSize,
  buttonStyle
)
```

2. The defaults for box-shadow contains a bug:

```js
export const buttonDefaults = {
  backgroundColor: `dark`,
  border: 'none',
  borderRadius: `2px`,
  color: `light`,
  fontSize: `body`,
  height: `36px`,
  lineHeight: `36px`,
  padding: `0 16px`,
  boxShadow: `box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
                          0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
                          0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`,
// remove the `box-shadow` declaration. Probably left over from a copy/paste
// Should be the following instead
boxShadow: `0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
                          0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 
                          0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`,
}
```

Here's a working fork [on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/learningstyledsystemandrebass-z2rym)

Comment: That did it -- thanks.  In terms of the comment about order -- I don't think order matters for the built-in setters, but it seems that the custom setters (in this case `buttonStyle` needs to go after all the built-in Styled-System setters.  Thanks again -- much appreciated.